# MongoDB: How can I filter specific Value from aggregate stage?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

My aggregate code

```
 const temp = await Employee.aggregate([
      {
        $unwind: { path: '$timeClocks', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true },
      },

      {
        $match: {
          _id: { $in: employees },
        },
      },

      {
        $group: {
          _id: '$_id',
          name: { $first: '$name' },
          timeClock: {
            $push: {
              start_time: '$timeClocks.start_time',
              end_time: '$timeClocks.end_time',
            },
          },
        },
      },
      // {
      //   $match: {
      //     timeClock: {
      //       start_time: new Date('2021-05-10'),
      //     },
      //   },
      // },
      // {
      //   $match: {
      //     timeClock: {
      //       start_time: {
      //         $gte: 'moment.utc(date).toDate()',
      //       },
      //     },
      //   },
      // },
      {
        $project: {
          name: 1,
          timeClock: 1,
        },
      },
    ]);
```

result

```
"working": [
      {
          "_id": "60cd9a3cb4ddcc00285b0df9",
          "name": "Dr. dd",
          "timeClock": [
              {
                  "start_time": "2021-05-04T02:19:00.000Z",
                  "end_time": "2021-05-04T14:42:00.000Z"
              },
              {
                  "start_time": "2021-05-02T08:12:00.000Z",
                  "end_time": "2021-05-02T22:24:00.000Z"
              },
              {
                  "start_time": "2021-05-10T20:14:00.000Z",
                  "end_time": "2021-05-10T22:17:00.000Z"
              },
          ]
      },
  ],
```

My situation now is when I aggregate from the collection, I get multiple values in `timeClock` field. But I'd like to have one matching date in `timeClock` field.
For example, if I want a date(2021-05-10), then

**Expected result**

```
"working": [
      {
          "_id": "60cd9a3cb4ddcc00285b0df9",
          "name": "Dr. dd",
          "timeClock": {
                  "start_time": "2021-05-10T02:19:00.000Z",
                  "end_time": "2021-05-1-T14:42:00.000Z"
              },
      },
  ],
```

I have tried adding `$match` and `$filter`, but gave me an empty array.

I am new to MongoDB can anyone tell me what I am missing from the aggregation stage??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "problem" with matching Date's (or date strings) is that an exact match is required.

I will show how to work around this for the Date type ( if your data is strings then I will briefly explain at the end what approach will work for that ).

So our approach will be to convert the convert the `start_time` field to be comparable using [$dateFromParts](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromParts/), like so:

```
const inputDate = new Date('2020-05-10');

....


[
    {
        $unwind: { path: '$timeClocks', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true },
    },
    {
        $match: {
            _id: { $in: employees },
        },
    },
    {
        $match: {
            $expr: {
                $eq: [
                    {
                        $dateFromParts : {
                            year: {$year: '$timeClocks.start_time'},
                            month: {$month: '$timeClocks.start_time'},
                            day: {$dayOfMonth: '$timeClocks.start_time'},
                        }
                    },
                    inputDate
                ]
            }
        },
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$_id',
            name: { $first: '$name' },
            timeClock: {
                $push: {
                    start_time: '$timeClocks.start_time',
                    end_time: '$timeClocks.end_time',
                },
            },
        },
    },
   // in your example this will be an array with 1 element. if this 
   //is always the case you can just use `$first` instead of `$push`.
]
```

If your dates are saved as `string` then you can use [$toDate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) to convert it and use the same pipeline if you're on Mongo v4.0+.
You can also compare strings and use `$split` on the `T` so that `"2021-05-04T02:19:00.000Z"` turns into `"2021-05-04"` however I never recommend matching strings when it comes to dates, amongst various issues you need to support ( like timezone / daylight savings and more ) you also have to guarantee all strings are in the same format for it to work.

Comment: Thank you so much for you time to answer my question. I was able to get the expected result! I am wondering through the pipeline if it executes top to bottom stage by stage? or it could be not ordered but the very last stage is the result?

Comment: Sorry if my question is not well explained because of my English skill

Comment: It is executed top to bottom, stage by stage.
i'm not sure what you mean exactly but each stage cannot run "independently"

Comment: thank you again for your answer I guess I understand how stages work now! Thank you so much